# PHP script to add values to text box and submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a domain like this and it has one text field and a submit button.

www.kimzdomain.com/addvalue

Input field name: add_value(text-box) & submit(Button)

Is there a way in which I can write a PHP script that will open this page (www.kimzdomain.com/register)  and add random value and hit the submit button so that the random value gets entered in my db.

This is a client requirement and I'm with no-clue.

In other words - a PHP script to add a random value in a page and click the submit button.

Comment: Use [`Goutte`](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte).

Comment: What is to happen once the button is clicked and the form submitted? Is it to return to the same page or somewhere else? Does the form have to be submitted using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

To open and run the php script, create a "cron job" in cpanel under "Advanced" right at the bottom of the page.

For random value, use the php rand() function.

Hope that helps.